# Cambiar de Fragmento Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment

estoy intentando cambiar de fragmento al presionar un botón, pero me aparece diversos errores, he visto mucho tutoriales pero la mayoría son en Java  y desde un Activity, en mi caso estoy en un fragmento.

```
class DiscoverFragment : BaseFragment(R.layout.fragment_discover) {
    private lateinit var viewModel: DiscoverViewModel

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(DiscoverViewModel::class.java)

        var nuevofragmento: Fragment = fragmentwebview

        likeone.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "one", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            val transaction = activity?.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            transaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, nuevofragmento)
            transaction.commit()

        }
```

}

También intente en mi Actividad

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity: BaseActivity(), NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener {
    private val homeViewModel by viewModels<MainViewModel>()


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {


        val fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment_inbox)
        fragmentTransaction.commit()
```

Pero me aparece el siguiente error

```
Classifier 'fragment_inbox' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el error está en esta línea `var nuevofragmento: Fragment = fragmentwebview`. Qué se supone que es `fragmentwebview`? no veo que esté declarada en ningún lado. Deberías crear una una instancia del fragment así: `Fragmentwebview()`

Pero igual estás haciendo todo al estilo Java. En Kotlin una transacción se hace así:

```
requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.commit {
    replace<Fragmentwebview>(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
}
```

y el viewModel se obtiene así: `private val viewModel: DiscoverViewModel by viewModels()`

Además ya no hace falta hacer las transacciones manualmente porque existe un componente para eso. Te recomiendo que leas un poco la [documentación oficial](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started)

Comment: Funciona perfecto

Comment: genial! pero igual deberías leer un poco de documentación. Hay mejores formas de manejar la navegación